# Display Buddypress code in Roots.io theme

Tags: php, wordpress, buddypress

I'm sort of new to Buddypress and I want to know if there is a way to override Buddypress and display Buddypress code in the Roots.io theme? I'm using BuddyPress version: 1.9.2 Wordpress version: 3.8.1.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All the information is in BuddyPress codex.

http://codex.buddypress.org/themes/theme-compatibility-1-7/template-hierarchy/
http://codex.buddypress.org/themes/theme-compatibility-1-7/a-quick-look-at-1-7-theme-compatibility/

And in general, open this page: http://codex.buddypress.org/themes/ - and in sidebar you will see and Subpages section.